# Iterate through date range - monthwise

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame containing datetime as a column. I wish to iterate over it for each month. Currently, I can slice it using 'pandas.query()' using a hard code as follows:

```
# For January 2018-
data_jan = data.query("opened_at >= '2018-01-02 00:00:00' and opened_at <= '2018-01-31 23:59:59'")
```

However, to iterate for each month, I was looking for a code. So far, the code I have is:

```
delta = timedelta(days = 30, hours = 0, minutes = 0, seconds = 0)

while start_date <= end_date:
    print(start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    start_date += delta
```

But, the while loop gives error:

> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Help?

Comment: What do you mean, to iterate by each month? Are there only one row for each month, or are there lots of rows with many months? Do you want to group by month, and aggregate by another column? Please post an example of your dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use month periods for [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) for groups by months:

```
months = df['opened_at'].dt.to_period('m')

for month, g in df.groupby(months):
    print (g)
```